# style of asciidoc Admonition missing while using Hugo ? ( syntax not supported? )

Tags: gitlab-ci, hugo, asciidoctor

I'm using Hugo to generate static pages in Gitlab, seems the syntax of asciidoc not supported well (such as [Admonition](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/syntax-quick-reference/#admonitions))? or it's just about the theme I'm using?

for code `[TIP]`

Expected:

[image: Expected]

Current:

[image: Current]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please enable font-based icons by adding

```
:icons: font
```

to your document. See [Font Icon Mode in AsciiDoc docs](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/macros/icons-font/) for details.
Depending on the CSS you use, the tool tip might look different. See below for the "classic" CSS of Asciidoctor.

[image]

Once you add the `:icons: font`, it is a matter of updating the CSS to make it look like your screenshot above.

Comment: after adding that attribute, the icon shows, and I found a useful repo 
 may help other peoples https://github.com/darshandsoni/asciidoctor-skins